# setting maxBufferPoolSize of basicHttpBinding programmatically

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, basichttpbinding

I am trying to set the maxBufferPoolSize along with MaxReceivedMessageSize and MaxBufferSize. However, when I try to set it, i got the message "'maxBufferPoolSize' is not a member of 'System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding'." I am using VS 2010. From MS Documentation, MaxBufferpoolSize is a member ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxbufferpoolsize). Why am I getting this error??? Please help. Thank you.

```
    Dim basicHttpBinding As BasicHttpBinding = New BasicHttpBinding()
    Dim endpointAddress As EndpointAddress = New EndpointAddress("/test.svc")
    basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = "2147483647"
    basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = "2147483647"
    **basicHttpBinding.maxBufferPoolSize = "2147483647"**


    basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0)
    basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)

    Dim Svc As Svc= New ChannelFactory(Of Svc)(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel
    '... do the binding
```

Comment: That code shouldn't compile. MaxReceivedMessageSize is of type Long, not String (as you're using). MaxBufferSize is of type Integer (again, not String). Try using numbers instead of string literals for those properties.

Comment: Is this on Silverlight? If so, there's no buffer pooling in SL, which is why you can't set that property.

Comment: you're right. It is silverlight. I am getting the data through the service using basichttpbinding. Sometimes data is populated, but sometimes it won't. I thought it may caused by not having enough pool for the connection... but i guess it is something else. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, you're using Silverlight, so that property doesn't exist in that framework. There's no buffer pooling in Silverlight, which is why it doesn't compile.